# FileNotFoundException using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, file, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to solve this problem for hours now and can't find a proper solution:
I am trying to Play a media File (Mp3/Ogg) but always get the FileNotFoundException (and I'm sure it's there ;) )

This is what I try:

Check if SD Card is available.

Check if reading/writing permissions are granted.

Load/Play Song.

```
if(isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable())
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("Permission","Readingpermission is granted");
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("Permission","Writingpermission is granted");
        }
        playSong(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString() + "/t1.mp3");
```

That part of the code is working so far.

But as soon as it comes to the playSong(String) :

```
try {
        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setDataSource(path);
        mediaplayer.prepare();
        mediaplayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Mediaplayer", e.toString());
    }
```

The program crashes trying to setDataSource with this Exception:

```
E/Mediaplayer: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/OMSclient.omsgui/files/Music/t1.mp3
```

What am I missing? I'm clueless.

---

Alright, I've found the following problem:

If I simply execute

```
playSong("storage/17E5-1C14/Android/data/OMSclient.omsgui/files/Music/t1.ogg");
```

It works fine, but if I Use:

```
playSong("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/OMSclient.omsgui/files/Music/t1.mp3");
```

or

```
playSong("storage/emulated/0/Android/data/OMSclient.omsgui/files/Music/t1.mp3");
```

It does not.

Why? ...

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: It's 19 and I need a minimum of 15 chars here to comment

Comment: I'm still thinking runtime permissions. What level is your emulator? Try an emulator that's 22 or less.

Comment: But if you have a look at my edit, it can play songs from an external SD card.... And it's not working on my phone either... Permissions for external write and read are granted

Comment: Just to be clear. "Readingpermission is granted" and "Writingpermission is granted" are printing to the log?

Comment: Yep, both stated in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Because getExternalFilesDir did not seem to work, I used the following workaround:

```
public String getExternalPath(){
    String removableStoragePath = "";
    File fileList[] = new File("/storage/").listFiles();
    for (File file : fileList)
    { if(!file.getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) && file.isDirectory() && file.canRead())
        removableStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath(); }
    return removableStoragePath;
}
```

This code worked fine on every Emulator I tested it.
Hope this helps, if somebody had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code,

```
 String filePath = "xx/xx/file.mp3";
 File file = new File(filePath);
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
 inputStream.close();
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: How you get your path?

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString()

Answer (score 0):

I created a project with the code you provided and the following properties:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19
```

And I discovered that `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString()` returns different values depending on the Android level of the emulator.

Level 19 KitKat 4.4
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.test.mediaplayerproblem/files/Music/test1.mp3

Level 25 Nougat 7.1.1
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.mediaplayerproblem/files/Music/test1.mp3

Here's my code that worked, but keep in mind I save the file from a raw resource and play it in the same activity so it will always be in the right place.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    private String musicDirPath;
    private String filename = "/test1.mp3";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        musicDirPath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString();
        TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText(musicDirPath + filename);
        Log.v("Mediaplayer", musicDirPath + filename);
    }

    public void playFile(View view) {
        if(isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable())
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("Permission","Readingpermission is granted");
            }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("Permission","Writingpermission is granted");
        }
        playSong(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString() + "/test1.mp3");
    }

    public void playSong(String path) {
        try {
            mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaplayer.prepare();
            mediaplayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Mediaplayer", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void stopFile(View view) {
        if (mediaplayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaplayer.stop();
                mediaplayer.release();
                mediaplayer = null;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveFile(View view) {

        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.finn1);
        int size = 0;

        try
        {
            size = fis.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            fis.read(buffer);
            fis.close();

            boolean exists = (new File(musicDirPath + filename)).exists();
            if (exists)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                FileOutputStream save = new FileOutputStream(musicDirPath + filename);
                save.write(buffer);
                save.flush();
                save.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "File saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.mediaplayerproblem.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/saveFile"
                android:text="Save"
                android:onClick="saveFile"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:text="Play"
                android:onClick="playFile"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/stopButton"
                android:text="Stop"
                android:onClick="stopFile"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! it seems like the problem is, that in my case
`getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString()`
returns
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/OMSclient.omsgui/files/Music`
but the SD card can not be accessed from
`/storage/emulated/0/`

Comment: I found a workaround in another question, if you don't have any further ideas why the code is not working as expected, I'll post that and close this question (The Workaround gets the direct Path to the SD card (`storage/17E5-1C14/` in my case)